# Set-Cookie header sets cookie to undefined

Tags: http, cookies, setcookie

I have a server that responds with this header **(no sensitive info in the token, don't worry)**

```
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiTmFtZWhlcmUiLCJzdXJuYW1lIjoiU3VybmFtZWhlcmUiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImVtYWlsQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ1c2VybmFtZWhlcmUiLCJhY2NvdW50VHlwZSI6InVzZXIiLCJjYW5Db21tZW50Ijp0cnVlLCJpZCI6IjAyMWJlNWZmLWQ3ZmUtNGVkZC1iM2U2LTIxZmQ3YTQzNzJiNSIsImlhdCI6MTY4MjIwOTgyNH0.Pr91G163CYt_8mnRbMPCFiCdyLv0Nh6_GcxjXjoEcGQ; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT
```

After the request tho, the cookie is set to `undefined`

This are the other Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2023 10:02:11 GMT
ETag: W/"25-YkNvLAfFYN55gV8geldjQoXlC5Y"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Powered-By: Express
```

These instead are the Request Headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 130
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the cookies we set are blocked/ignored by the browser if the samesite attribute is not defined when you set the cookie. Also using HTTP can also be a factor that makes some cookies to be ignored.

What to set it to, all depends on your needs and use of the cookie.

check this article for more details about samesite

- [Developers: Get Ready for New SameSite=None; Secure Cookie Settings](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html)
- [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: even setting `SameSite` does not save the cookie